# How can I convert standard TXT files to Evernote's notes

Tags: evernote

I have a bunch of txt files exported from Simplenote, which I want to import to Evernote.

I know Evernote can only import enex format, but how can I convert the txt files to an enex file?

I noticed there is a web app called Simple For Ever can do this but it adds some restrictions to my notes, adding background color and making them read only. I'm wondering how does this web app work? is it possible to programmingly generate enex file and how?

Answer (score 1):

For the following, Evernote will open and your text files will be in there as Evernote notes. It certainly works for TXT, RTF, DOC(X), other filetypes untested.

Windows:

1. Select all the text files you want in Evernote.
2. Right click on them.
3. Go to "Send to".
4. Click on "Evernote".

Mac:

1. Select all the text files you want in Evernote.
2. Right click on them.
3. Go to "Services" (on the bottom).
4. Click on "Add to Evernote".